# How can I get Outlook 2010 to show my upcoming appointments from sync'd calendars?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a regular calendar and alternate calendar that I sync with Outlook 2010, iPad and iPhone. The to do bar shows no appointments.  How can I get the sync'd calendar appoints to show in the upcoming appointments?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the To-Do bar only displays appointments from the default Outlook calendar. It will not display any information from any secondary calendar in the To-Do bar. I have not been able to find official confirmation for this, but you can see [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-outlook/multiple-calendars-in-to-do-bar/f21f3c05-a032-435d-ab69-e6a51986a616) or [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-calendars-show/df213898-1344-4c4b-bc82-bbb99a340ee2) thread at Microsoft Community.
Your only option would be to sync to the default Outlook calendar.